# Writing to different columns in CSV

Tags: python, csv

I know this question has been asked a few times but I have tried everything and nothing seems to work I think I just need a 2nd set of eyes to tell me what I am doing wrong.

I am currently able to write to my CSV file like this

```
Row 1: Date
Row 2: User_Name
Row 3: Text
etc..
```

But I want to write to it like

```
Column1   Column2       Column3
Date      User_Name      Text
```

Here is my code

```
writer = csv.writer(open('test.csv', 'ab'))
r = api.request('search/tweets', {'q':'pizza'})
for item in r:
    screen_name = item['user']['screen_name'].encode('utf-8')
    created_at = item['created_at'].encode('utf-8')
    tweet = item['text'].encode('utf-8')
    writer.writerows([screen_name, created_at, tweet])
```

my current output with this code looks like this

```
d,o,m,i,n,o,s
W,e,d, ,O,c,t, ,2,8, ,1,9,:,0,1,:,1,6, ,+,0,0,0,0, ,2,0,1,5
@,G,i,a,n,k,i,5,8,9,6, ,T,r,y,i,n,g, ,t,o, ,o,r,d,e,r,?, ,L,e,a,r,n, ,h,o,w, ,t,o, ,e,n,a,b,l,e, ,T,w,e,e,t, ,O,r,d,e,r,i,n,g, ,i,n, ,y,o,u,r, ,P,i,z,z,a, ,P,r,o,f,i,l,e,:, ,h,t,t,p,s,:,/,/,t,.,c,o,/,z,U,m,E,c,Y,M,6,5,2, ,[,1,5,:,0,1,:,2,2, ,E,D,T,]
K,_,_,B,o,o,k,s
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: looks like `api.request` is return a string which means `item in r` are individual characters. try calling `.split` on r to get a list of all the individual words

Comment: You're mixing up two tasks here, *getting* rows with the api.request and *writing* them into the CSV.  For the problem with this name, define row data (hint: in the format that `csv.writer.writerows` uses in docs/examples).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either call [`.writerow()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) inside the loop:

```
for item in r:
    screen_name = item['user']['screen_name'].encode('utf-8')
    created_at = item['created_at'].encode('utf-8')
    tweet = item['text'].encode('utf-8')
    writer.writerow([screen_name, created_at, tweet])
```

Or, collect the rows in a list of lists and call [`.writerows()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) after:

```
rows = []
for item in r:
    screen_name = item['user']['screen_name'].encode('utf-8')
    created_at = item['created_at'].encode('utf-8')
    tweet = item['text'].encode('utf-8')    
    rows.append([screen_name, created_at, tweet])

writer.writerows(rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

`writerows`, as the name implies, is used to write multiple rows. It looks like you want to write one row per `item`, so use `writerow([screen_name, created_at, tweeet])` instead.

As it is, `writerows` is receiving a sequence of three strings per item. `writerows` expects a sequence of sequences, and writes one row for each sequence (a string, in this case) in the main sequence. Thus, each character in the string gets written to a separate column.

Comment: Again your answer is totally right missed row vs rows! thank you for your help